# Unplugging pendrives without unmounting them in embedded Linux system

Tags: linux, mount, embedded

I need to write a program for embedded Linux that services mounting and unmounting pendrives. My problem appears when the device is not unmounted in a proper way. When the user disconnects a device without asking for unmounting, after next plugging, the same device is seen as a different device in the /dev directory, i.e. first it was seen as /dev/sdb1, then it was unplugged without unmounting and after replugging it is seen as /dev/sdc1 etc. This problem does not occur if the device is properly unmounted, but my program is supposed to assume that the user will not always remember this. The device is supposed to be rebooted very rarely. What should I do to avoid creating new devices /dev/sdc1, /dev/sdd1 etc.?

**EDIT:** When I list my mount points using `mount` command, all unplugged but unmounted devices are visible in the list. I am not able to remove mount point directory because I always get error `rm: cannot remove '/tmp/mount_point/': Device or resource busy`.

Comment: Read `man -a sync;man fssync`. If you use `sync` after each bunch of writes, the system will flush the buffers.

Comment: Have you tried "unmount-l" (lowercase L)